# Почему в цикле после appendChild прекращает работать цикл?

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

```js
var taskid = [3, 5, 6];
var taskpr = [1, 2, 2];
var taskname = ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3'];

for (var t = 0; t < taskid.length; t++) {
  console.log(t);

  var list = document.getElementById('fortask' + taskpr[t]);
  console.log(list);
  list.setAttribute("class", "adds");

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.setAttribute('id', 'lik' + taskid[t]);
  li.classList.add('lid');

  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.classList.add('checkbox');
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'checkbox' + taskpr[t] + taskid[t]);

  var text = document.createElement('input');
  text.classList.add('taskname');
  text.innerText = taskname[t];
  text.placeholder = taskname[t];
  text.setAttribute('id', 'name' + taskpr[t] + taskid[t]);
  text.setAttribute('disabled', true);

  var line1 = document.createElement('div');
  line1.classList.add('line1');

  li.appendChild(checkbox);
  li.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(line1);

  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul id="fortask1"></ul>
  <ul id="fortask2"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Создайте пример кода, который можно запустить, с помощью кнопки "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: ты создала элемент `list`: `document.createElement('fortask' + taskpr[t])` (скорее всего хотела создать `ul`) - но не добавила его в DOM, поэтому ты его никак и не увидела.

Comment: @Grundy в начало цикла закинула даже console.log, даже его не выводит

Comment: Позволил себе отредактировать задачу, вставив код в сниппет обладая данными о 2ух массивах, словил ошибку, что `taskname` не определен, добавил этот массив, все работает. Вывод: выложите полную реализацию, иначе не ясно что с вашим кодом не так.

Answer (score 1):

Пока я вижу в консоли ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: taskname is not defined
```

taskname по определению `text.classList.add('taskname');` - это присвоенный класс созданному тегу  input, в самой функции такой переменной нет. Поэтому `text.innerText = taskname[t];` не работает и код дальше не выполняется.

Кроме этого непонятна строка `var list = document.createElement('fortask' + taskpr[t])` , в которой Вы создаёте элемент `<fortask>`? Это так задумано?

Comment: да, у меня в коде HTML есть: <ul id="fortask1"></ul>
  <ul id="fortask2"></ul> и получается нужно, чтобы одна группа элементов пошла в фортаск1, а две группы в фортаск2, а вставляется только самая первая и все, если цикл делаю в обратную сторону, то только последняя группа

Comment: Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю, тогда от меня мало пользы в этом вопросе, но как по мне, то элемент <ul id="fortask1"></ul> это стандартный  тег <ul> , имеющий id="fortask", а var list = document.createElement('fortask' + taskpr[t]); создаёт собственные теги <fortask1> и <fortask2> , но я не особо знаком как отображаются собственные теги в браузерах. В любом случае, если Вы замените taskname  в строках text.innerText = taskname[t];
    text.placeholder = taskname[t];, то цикл выполняется.

Comment: Проблема решена, оказалось, что у меня две переменные с одинаковым именем t

Comment: Ну, и это тоже...